# CUDA 5.5 & Intel C/C++ Compiler on Linux

Tags: linux, cuda, nvcc, icc

For my current project, I need to use CUDA and the Intel C/C++ compilers in the same project. (I rely on the SSYEV implementation of Intel's MKL, which takes roughly 10 times as long when using GCC+MKL instead of ICC+MKL (~3ms from GCC, ~300µs from ICC).

```
icc -v
icc version 12.1.5
```

NVIDIA states, that Intel ICC 12.1 is supported (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#linux-platforms-supported), but even after having downgraded to Intel ICC 12.1.5 (installed as part of the Intel Composer XE 2011 SP1 Update 3), I am still running into this issue:

```
nvcc -ccbin=icc src/test.cu -o test
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin//..//include/host_config.h(72): catastrophic error: #error directive: -- unsupported ICC configuration! Only ICC 12.1 on Linux x86_64 is supported!
#error -- unsupported ICC configuration! Only ICC 12.1 on Linux x86_64 is supported!
```

Unfortunately, it seems as if Nvidia is merely tolerating the use of ICC, because I would hardly call it "support", given the lack of information provided by Nvidia for using ICC together with CUDA.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 x86_64 and CUDA 5.5. Telling icc to mimick the behavior of the stock GCC 4.7.2 using the `-Xcompiler -gcc-version=470` option did not help either. Using google/search, I was only able to find threads from the Nvidia forums dealing with CUDA 3.x and Intel ICC 11.1, but I was unable to transfer the obtained information to current CUDA releases.

I would be very grateful for any suggestion on how to solving this issue :-)

Comment: Ok, so I was able to bypass the problem by removing the macro checking for the ICC version from `/usr/local/cuda-5.5/include/host_config.h`. With these changes in place, my application both compiles and runs - even when using Intel ICC 13.1.3. However, I am curious if there exists a proper/cleaner method which doesn't involve messing with the CUDA headers...

Comment: You can certainly bypass the host config check.  Then you are in uncharted (i.e. untested) waters.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the file referenced in the error you received, it's specifically looking for an ICC compiler with a particular build date:

```
#if defined(__ICC)

#if !(__INTEL_COMPILER == 9999 && __INTEL_COMPILER_BUILD_DATE == 20110811) || !defined(__GNUC__) || !defined(__LP64__)

#error -- unsupported ICC configuration! Only ICC 12.1 on Linux x86_64 is supported!

#endif
```

The solution would be to have the intel compiler that actually matches that specified build date.  As indicated, [ICC 12.1](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compiler-and-composer-update-version-numbers-to-compiler-version-number-mapping), ie. version 12.1.0.233, instead of ICC 12.1.5 should do the trick.

The narrow focus is at least partly due to a test limitation.  In this case, a particular ICC variant was tested with the CUDA toolkit before it was released, and so that host config check has this test in it.

Comment: My main problem was or rather is that having to rely on the free academic version of ICC, there is no simple way to retrieve said exact version. (At least I did not find the correct version in any of the free Composer XE bundles provided by Intel). I have decided I am willing to take the risk my toolchain might suddenly explode and will go for the unsupported configuration :-)

Answer (score 0):

I  confronted the problem when compiling madagascar-1.5 with icc2013 and ifort2013. Then I try to resolve the problem by downloading ICC version 2011 update7. Based the INTEL_COMPILER_BUILD_DATE which is 20110811, I can download the correct one. I think the date 20110811 matched icc is the correct one.