# Unresolved references using IFORT with nvcc and CUSP

Tags: c++, cuda, fortran, intel-fortran, cusp-library

I have a program which I'm compiling like this:

```
(...) Some ifort *.f -c
nvcc -c src/bicgstab.cu -o bicgstab.o -I/home/ricardo/apps/cusp/cusplibrary
(...) Some more *.for -c
ifort *.o -L/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64 -lcudart -lcublas -lcusparse -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -openmp -o program
```

Everything worked fine until i added the CUSP support where i have this wrapper (bicgstab.cu):

```
#include <cusp/csr_matrix.h>
#include <cusp/krylov/bicgstab.h>

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

void bicgstab_(int * device_I, int * device_J, float * device_V, float * device_x, float * device_b, int N, int NNZ){

    // *NOTE* raw pointers must be wrapped with thrust::device_ptr!
    thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_I(device_I);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_J(device_J);
    thrust::device_ptr<float> wrapped_device_V(device_V);
    thrust::device_ptr<float> wrapped_device_x(device_x);
    thrust::device_ptr<float> wrapped_device_b(device_b);

    // use array1d_view to wrap the individual arrays
    typedef typename cusp::array1d_view< thrust::device_ptr<int> > DeviceIndexArrayView;
    typedef typename cusp::array1d_view< thrust::device_ptr<float> > DeviceValueArrayView;

    DeviceIndexArrayView row_indices (wrapped_device_I, wrapped_device_I + (N+1));
    DeviceIndexArrayView column_indices(wrapped_device_J, wrapped_device_J + NNZ);
    DeviceValueArrayView values (wrapped_device_V, wrapped_device_V + NNZ);
    DeviceValueArrayView x (wrapped_device_x, wrapped_device_x + N);
    DeviceValueArrayView b (wrapped_device_b, wrapped_device_b + N);

    // combine the three array1d_views into a csr_matrix_view
    typedef cusp::csr_matrix_view<DeviceIndexArrayView,
    DeviceIndexArrayView,
    DeviceValueArrayView> DeviceView;

    // construct a csr_matrix_view from the array1d_views
    DeviceView A(N, N, NNZ, row_indices, column_indices, values);

    // set stopping criteria:
    // iteration_limit = 100
    // relative_tolerance = 1e-5
    cusp::verbose_monitor<float> monitor(b, 100, 1e-5);

    // solve the linear system A * x = b with the Conjugate Gradient method
    cusp::krylov::bicgstab(A, x, b, monitor);

}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

Nvcc compiles and generate the object, but in the last command when i'm linking all together a bunch of errors because of the linking appears:

```
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __gxx_personality_v0
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTVSt9exception
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTVSt9bad_alloc
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZdlPv
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_guard_acquire
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSaIcEC1Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_guard_release
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSsD1Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSaIcED1Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_guard_abort
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSsC1ERKSs
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSt13runtime_errorD2Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_call_unexpected
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSt13runtime_errorC2ERKSs
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSsC1Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNKSs5emptyEv
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNKSt13runtime_error4whatEv
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSsaSEPKc
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSspLEPKc
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSspLERKSs
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_begin_catch
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_end_catch
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNKSs5c_strEv
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNKSt9bad_alloc4whatEv
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSt9bad_allocD2Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_allocate_exception
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_free_exception
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_throw
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSt9exceptionD2Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZSt4cout
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSolsEf
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSolsEm
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZSt9terminatev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZStlsIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_St5_Setw
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSolsEPFRSt8ios_baseS0_E
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSt9bad_allocD1Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTISt9bad_alloc
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved __cxa_pure_virtual
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTISt9exception
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTISt13runtime_error
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        Referenced in bicgstab.o
```

I believe that its because ifort is adding or removing underscores, adding lower/upper cases or anything else because the file is compiling write and if i generate the binary outside my program, just for testing, it works great.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what happens if you put your cusp `#include` statements inside the `extern "C" {` wrapper?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same...

Comment: Depending on which icc version you have, you could try to [specify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698817/cuda-5-5-intel-c-c-compiler-on-linux) to `nvcc` to use `icc` instead of `gcc`.  ifort might be happier about linking to objects produced by icc rather than gcc in this instance. If you add a simple fortran module to your question that just calls this function in bicgstab.cu, and the actual commands to compile and link them together, I'll take another look.  I tried doing something like that with intel 12.1 tools and was not able to reproduce the linkage issue (warnings, actually?).

Comment: [here's](http://pastebin.com/RZbx9U33) my example which seems to compile/link correctly.  I admit the fortran program I wrote is bogus, but it's just to demonstrate link-ability.  I happened to be using CUDA 6.0 with intel 12.1 tools, RHEL 6.2 with gcc 4.4.6

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help!

I've tested with your example and it works. And i found what the problem is: the -fast flag which adds the ipo optimizations. If i remove the -ipo optimization by substituting the -fast with -O3 (and removing the -ipo which is only there as a reminder since -fast includes it) it works, but my program has a substantially drop in performance without the -ipo so i really need to figure out what the problem is..

I also tried to use -ccbin=icc in the nvcc but i have icc 13 and it gives me an error that only supports icc 12.1.

Comment: If you compile your code with -fast in ifort i think you also can see the problem...

Comment: Note they are warnings, not errors. I have couple of these in my code and they are harmless. Do you also have some actual errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ipo is fairly complicated when there are multiple files involved.   It's actually rerunning the compiler on all modules at link time.  I'm not an expert on this, but that sounds like something fairly difficult to wade through.

One possible option might be that you try to compile your cuda code into a shared library (.so) and link against that.  It should prevent the intel compiler toolchain from trying to recompile and optimize against the code generated by nvcc/gcc.  I think this is going to limit you to "single file optimizations".  Don't know if that will significantly affect your performance or not.

Using my example [here](http://pastebin.com/RZbx9U33), I would modify the compile commands as follows:

```
$ nvcc -Xcompiler="-fPIC" -shared bicgstab.cu -o bicgstab.so -I/home-2/robertc/misc/cusp/cusplibrary-master
$ ifort -c -fast bic.f90
$ ifort bic.o bicgstab.so -L/shared/apps/cuda/CUDA-v6.0.37/lib64 -lcudart  -o program
ipo: remark #11001: performing single-file optimizations
ipo: remark #11006: generating object file /tmp/ipo_ifortxEdpin.o
$
```

You don't indicate where in your compile process you are adding the `-fast` switch(es).  If only on the `ifort` compile commands, I believe the above approach will work.  If you also want/need it on the link command, then it appears that ifort wants to build an entirely statically linked executable (and do intermodule optimization...), which won't work using the above process.

Comment: In my particular example above, the `-L/shared/apps/cuda/CUDA-v6.0.37/lib64 -lcudart` is not actually necessary on the `ifort` link command, because in my case the only actual CUDA usage is in the shared object.  Your case may be different.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Using as a shared library worked fined!