# Generating CUSP coo_matrix from passed FORTRAN arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, fortran, cusp-library

I am working on integrating CUSP solvers into an existing FORTRAN code. As a first step, I am simply trying to pass in a pair of integer arrays and a float (real*4 in FORTRAN) from FORTRAN which will be used to construct and then print a COO format CUSP matrix.

So far, I have been able to follow this thread and got everything to compile and link: [Unresolved references using IFORT with nvcc and CUSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462580/unresolved-references-using-ifort-with-nvcc-and-cusp)

Unfortunately, the program is apparently sending garbage into the CUSP matrix and ends up crashing with the following error:

```
$./fort_cusp_test
 testing 1 2 3
sparse matrix <1339222572, 1339222572> with 1339222568 entries
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type thrust::system::system_error: invalid argument

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x10ff86ff6
#1  0x10ff86593
#2  0x7fff8593ff19
Abort trap: 6
```

The code for the cuda and fortran sources are as follows:

**cusp_runner.cu**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cusp/coo_matrix.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cusp/krylov/cg.h>
#include <cusp/print.h>

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

void test_coo_mat_print_(int * row_i, int * col_j, float * val_v, int n, int nnz ) {

   //wrap raw input pointers with thrust::device_ptr
   thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_I(row_i);
   thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_J(col_j);
   thrust::device_ptr<float> wrapped_device_V(val_v);

   //use array1d_view to wrap individual arrays
   typedef typename cusp::array1d_view< thrust::device_ptr<int> > DeviceIndexArrayView;
   typedef typename cusp::array1d_view< thrust::device_ptr<float> > DeviceValueArrayView;

   DeviceIndexArrayView row_indices(wrapped_device_I, wrapped_device_I + n);
   DeviceIndexArrayView column_indices(wrapped_device_J, wrapped_device_J + nnz);
   DeviceValueArrayView values(wrapped_device_V, wrapped_device_V + nnz);

   //combine array1d_views into coo_matrix_view
   typedef   cusp::coo_matrix_view<DeviceIndexArrayView,DeviceIndexArrayView,DeviceValueArrayView> DeviceView;

   //construct coo_matrix_view from array1d_views
   DeviceView A(n,n,nnz,row_indices,column_indices,values);

   cusp::print(A);
}
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

**fort_cusp_test.f90**

```
program fort_cuda_test

   implicit none

interface
   subroutine test_coo_mat_print_(row_i,col_j,val_v,n,nnz) bind(C)
      use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_INT,C_FLOAT
      implicit none
      integer(C_INT) :: n, nnz, row_i(:), col_j(:)
      real(C_FLOAT) :: val_v(:)
   end subroutine test_coo_mat_print_
end interface

   integer*4   n
   integer*4   nnz

   integer*4, target :: rowI(9),colJ(9)
   real*4, target :: valV(9)

   integer*4, pointer ::   row_i(:)
   integer*4, pointer ::   col_j(:)
   real*4, pointer ::   val_v(:)

   n     =  3
   nnz   =  9
   rowI =  (/ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3/)
   colJ =  (/ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3/)
   valV =  (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9/)

   row_i => rowI
   col_j => colJ
   val_v => valV

   write(*,*) "testing 1 2 3"

   call test_coo_mat_print_(row_i,col_j,val_v,n,nnz)

end program fort_cuda_test
```

If you want to try it yourself, here is my (rather inelegant) makefile:

```
Test:
   nvcc -Xcompiler="-fPIC" -shared cusp_runner.cu -o cusp_runner.so -I/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.5/include/cusp
   gfortran -c fort_cusp_test.f90
   gfortran fort_cusp_test.o cusp_runner.so -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.5/lib -lcudart -o fort_cusp_test

clean:
   rm *.o *.so
```

The library paths will need to be changed as appropriate of course.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to properly pass in the needed arrays from the fortran code?

---

with the interface block removed and addition of a print statement at the start of the C function I can see that the arrays are being passed correctly, but n and nnz are causing problems.
I get the following output:

```
$ ./fort_cusp_test
 testing 1 2 3
n: 1509677596, nnz: 1509677592
     i,  row_i,  col_j,        val_v
     0,      1,      1,   1.0000e+00
     1,      1,      2,   2.0000e+00
     2,      1,      3,   3.0000e+00
     3,      2,      1,   4.0000e+00
     4,      2,      2,   5.0000e+00
     5,      2,      3,   6.0000e+00
     6,      3,      1,   7.0000e+00
     7,      3,      2,   8.0000e+00
     8,      3,      3,   9.0000e+00
     9,      0,  32727,   0.0000e+00
    ...
    etc
    ...
    Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x105ce7ff6
#1  0x105ce7593
#2  0x7fff8593ff19
#3  0x105c780a2
#4  0x105c42dbc
#5  0x105c42df4
Segmentation fault: 11
```

**fort_cusp_test**

```
    interface
       subroutine test_coo_mat_print_(row_i,col_j,val_v,n,nnz) bind(C)
          use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_INT,C_FLOAT
          implicit none
          integer(C_INT),value :: n, nnz
          integer(C_INT) :: row_i(:), col_j(:)
          real(C_FLOAT) :: val_v(:)
       end subroutine test_coo_mat_print_
    end interface

       integer*4   n
       integer*4   nnz

       integer*4, target :: rowI(9),colJ(9)
       real*4, target :: valV(9)

       integer*4, pointer ::   row_i(:)
       integer*4, pointer ::   col_j(:)
       real*4, pointer ::   val_v(:)

       n     =  3
       nnz   =  9
       rowI =  (/ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3/)
       colJ =  (/ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3/)
       valV =  (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9/)

       row_i => rowI
       col_j => colJ
       val_v => valV

       write(*,*) "testing 1 2 3"

       call test_coo_mat_print_(rowI,colJ,valV,n,nnz)

    end program fort_cuda_test
```

**cusp_runner.cu**

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cusp/coo_matrix.h>
    #include <iostream>
    // #include <cusp/krylov/cg.h>
    #include <cusp/print.h>

    #if defined(__cplusplus)
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    void test_coo_mat_print_(int * row_i, int * col_j, float * val_v, int n, int nnz ) {

       printf("n: %d, nnz: %d\n",n,nnz);

       printf("%6s, %6s, %6s, %12s \n","i","row_i","col_j","val_v");
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
          printf("%6d, %6d, %6d, %12.4e\n",i,row_i[i],col_j[i],val_v[i]);
       }
       if ( false ) {
       //wrap raw input pointers with thrust::device_ptr
       thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_I(row_i);
       thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_J(col_j);
       thrust::device_ptr<float> wrapped_device_V(val_v);

       //use array1d_view to wrap individual arrays
       typedef typename cusp::array1d_view< thrust::device_ptr<int> > DeviceIndexArrayView;
       typedef typename cusp::array1d_view< thrust::device_ptr<float> > DeviceValueArrayView;

       DeviceIndexArrayView row_indices(wrapped_device_I, wrapped_device_I + n);
       DeviceIndexArrayView column_indices(wrapped_device_J, wrapped_device_J + nnz);
       DeviceValueArrayView values(wrapped_device_V, wrapped_device_V + nnz);

       //combine array1d_views into coo_matrix_view
       typedef cusp::coo_matrix_view<DeviceIndexArrayView,DeviceIndexArrayView,DeviceValueArrayView> DeviceView;

       //construct coo_matrix_view from array1d_views
       DeviceView A(n,n,nnz,row_indices,column_indices,values);

       cusp::print(A); }
    }
    #if defined(__cplusplus)
    }
    #endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods for passing arguments from Fortran to C routines: The first is to use the interface block (a new approach in modern Fortran), and the second is not to use the interface block (an old approach valid even for Fortran77).

First, the following is about the first method for using the interface block. Because the C routine expects to receive C pointers (row_i, col_j, and val_v), we need to pass the address for those variables from the Fortran side. To do so, we have to use asterisk (*) rather than colon(:) in the interface block, as shown below. (If we use colon, then this tells the Fortran compiler to send the address of Fortran pointer objects [1], which is not the desired behavior.) Also, since n and nnz in the C routine are declared as values (not pointers), the interface block needs to have the VALUE attribute for these variables, so that the Fortran compiler sends the value of n and nnz rather than their addresses. To summarize, in this first approach, the C and Fortran routines look like this:

```
Fortran routine:
...
interface
    subroutine test_coo_mat_print_(row_i,col_j,val_v,n,nnz) bind(C)
        use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_INT,C_FLOAT
        implicit none
        integer(C_INT) :: row_i(*), col_j(*)
        real(C_FLOAT) :: val_v(*)
        integer(C_INT), value :: n, nnz     !! see note [2] below also
    end subroutine test_coo_mat_print_
end interface
...
call test_coo_mat_print_( rowI, colJ, valV, n, nnz )

C routine:
void test_coo_mat_print_ (int * row_i, int * col_j, float * val_v, int n, int nnz )
```

---

The following is about the second approach without the interface block. In this approach, first delete the interface block and array pointers entirely, and change the Fortran code as follows

```
Fortran routine:

integer  rowI( 9 ), colJ( 9 ), n, nnz     !! no TARGET attribute necessary
real     valV( 9 )

! ...set rowI etc as above...

call test_coo_mat_print ( rowI, colJ, valV, n, nnz )   !! "_" is dropped
```

and the C routine as follows

```
void test_coo_mat_print_ ( int* row_i, int* col_j, float* val_v, int* n_, int* nnz_ )
{
    int n = *n_, nnz = *nnz_;

    printf( "%d %d \n", n, nnz );
    for( int k = 0; k < 9; k++ ) {
        printf( "%d %d %10.6f \n", row_i[ k ], col_j[ k ], val_v[ k ] );
    }

    // now go to thrust...
}
```

Note that n_ and nnz_ are declared as pointers in the C routine, because without the interface block, the Fortran compiler always sends the address of actual arguments to the C routine. Also note that in the above C routine, the contents of row_i etc are printed to make sure that the arguments are passed correctly. If the printed values are correct, then I guess the problem will be more likely in the call of thrust routines (including how to pass the size info like n and nnz).

[1] Fortran pointers declared as "real, pointer :: a(:)" actually represents something like an array view class (in C++ jargon), which is different from the actual data pointed. What is needed here is to send the address of actual data, not the address of this array-view object. Also, the asterisk in the interface block (a(*)) represents an assumed-size array, which is an old method for passing an array in Fortran. In this case the address of the first element of the array is passed, as expected.

[2] If n and nnz are declared as pointers in the C routine (as in the second approach), then this VALUE attribute should *not* be attached, because the C routine wants the address of actual arguments rather than their values.

Comment: I tried the modification you show above, but I'm now getting a thrust error instead: $ ./fort_cusp_test 
 testing 1 2 3
sparse matrix <3, 3> with 9 entries
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Could you check whether all the arguments (rowI, colJ, ..., nnz) are correctly passed to the C routine by printing their values at the top of the C routine? I think it would also be a good check to modify the value of rowI[8] & valV[8] etc in the C routine, immediately return to the Fortran routine (without calling any thrust ones), and verify if the values are modified in the Fortran side as well. I believe it is important to make sure that the variables are passed correctly first.

Comment: As for thrust, sorry, I have no experience with it and so cannot go further... However, it would be useful for other SO people to know what line of the C code the "thrust::system::system_error" was raised. Another point of my concern is that "wrapped_device_V" seems not defined in the C code (just dropped when copying to the Question?), and whether the use of n and nnz in making "DeviceIndexArrayView" and "DeviceView" are consistent with Fortran array data (which I cannot see because I don't know thrust...)

Comment: I tried removing the interface block and adding a printing statement (see updated OP). It looks like the arrays are passed correctly, but n and nnz are wrong. Do I need to add a %value flag to pass them? That seems rather odd since they are scalars.

Comment: In my environment (CentOS-6 64bit + gfort4.8), n and nnz are passed both with and without the interface block. Did you also try changing the declaration of n and nnz in the C routine (from values to pointers)? Without the interface block, Fortran always passes the address of variables, so we have to use pointers in the C side.

Comment: And, sorry for confusing comments, but if you use the interface block (as edited in your Question), you need to replace colons to asterisks as `integer(C_INT) :: row_i(*), col_j(*) ;  real(C_FLOAT) :: val_v(*)`. This asterisk tells the Fortran compilers to send the address of those variables, while the VALUE attribute to send the values of the variables. If you remove the VALUE attribute in the interface block, the compiler will send the address of n and nnz (so they need to be declared as pointers in the C side, as in the Edit in the Answer). So a bit confusing, sorry for mixed explanation.

Comment: ah! good to know. I am still quite new to interfacing C and fortran. I got the three variables to pass correctly by updating the c code to have n and nnz as pointers then dereferencing them into scalars inside the c code. The printing statement indicates the expected results. So it looks like from here out it is a thrust specific error now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Nice if it worked well :D I have updated the Answer so that it wil be a bit more clear (because two methods were explained in a mixed way...). Hope the expalanation is now clear. Cheers :)

Comment: Now that the variables are being sent correctly, I can see that the error happens when I try to build A from the DeviceIndexArrayView and DeviceValueArrayView objects.

Comment: In that case, it may be useful to post a new Question now focusing on the usage of the thrust routine, by attaching "thrust" tag (see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thrust ). Even attaching "trust" tag to this Question would be useful. If the problem is in the thrust side, it is probably more clear to separate the problem from Fortran, e.g., by declaring row_i etc at the top of the C routine rather than receiving as arguments (so no Fortran routine).