# How to properly construct CUSP coo matrix from passed arrays

Tags: c++, cuda, fortran, thrust, cusp-library

I am trying to integrate CUSP into an existing Fortran code. Right now I am just trying to get the basic set up for thrust / CUSP to feed in arrays from Fortran and use them to construct a CUSP matrix (coo format right now).
I have been able to get a wrapper like C routine to compile into a library and link it with the Fortran code thanks to this thread: [unresolved-references-using-ifort-with-nvcc-and-cusp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462580/unresolved-references-using-ifort-with-nvcc-and-cusp)

And I can verify that Fortran is correctly feeding in array pointers thanks to help from a previous thread: [Generating CUSP coo_matrix from passed FORTRAN arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020853/generating-cusp-coo-matrix-from-passed-fortran-arrays)

Unfortunately, I still can not get CUSP to use these to generate and print a matrix.
The code and output are shown below:

**output**

```
$ ./fort_cusp_test
 testing 1 2 3
n: 3, nnz: 9
     i,  row_i,  col_j,        val_v
     0,      1,      1,   1.0000e+00
     1,      1,      2,   2.0000e+00
     2,      1,      3,   3.0000e+00
     3,      2,      1,   4.0000e+00
     4,      2,      2,   5.0000e+00
     5,      2,      3,   6.0000e+00
     6,      3,      1,   7.0000e+00
     7,      3,      2,   8.0000e+00
     8,      3,      3,   9.0000e+00
initialized row_i into thrust
initialized col_j into thrust
initialized val_v into thrust
defined CUSP integer array view for row_i and col_j
defined CUSP float array view for val_v
loaded row_i into a CUSP integer array view
loaded col_j into a CUSP integer array view
loaded val_v into a CUSP float array view
defined CUSP coo_matrix view
Built matrix A from CUSP device views
sparse matrix <3, 3> with 9 entries
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type thrust::system::system_error: invalid argument

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x10d0fdff6
#1  0x10d0fd593
#2  0x7fff8593ff19
Abort trap: 6
```

**fort_cusp_test.f90**

```
program fort_cuda_test

   implicit none

 ! interface
 !    subroutine test_coo_mat_print_(row_i,col_j,val_v,n,nnz) bind(C)
 !       use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_INT,C_FLOAT
 !       implicit none
 !       integer(C_INT),value :: n, nnz
 !       integer(C_INT) :: row_i(:), col_j(:)
 !       real(C_FLOAT) :: val_v(:)
 !    end subroutine test_coo_mat_print_
 ! end interface

   integer*4   n
   integer*4   nnz

   integer*4, target :: rowI(9),colJ(9)
   real*4, target :: valV(9)

   integer*4, pointer ::   row_i(:)
   integer*4, pointer ::   col_j(:)
   real*4, pointer ::   val_v(:)

   n     =  3
   nnz   =  9
   rowI =  (/ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3/)
   colJ =  (/ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3/)
   valV =  (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9/)

   row_i => rowI
   col_j => colJ
   val_v => valV

   write(*,*) "testing 1 2 3"

   call test_coo_mat_print (rowI,colJ,valV,n,nnz)

end program fort_cuda_test
```

**cusp_runner.cu**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cusp/coo_matrix.h>
#include <iostream>
// #include <cusp/krylov/cg.h>
#include <cusp/print.h>

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

void test_coo_mat_print_(int * row_i, int * col_j, float * val_v, int * N, int * NNZ ) {

   int n, nnz;

   n = *N;
   nnz = *NNZ;

   printf("n: %d, nnz: %d\n",n,nnz);

   printf("%6s, %6s, %6s, %12s \n","i","row_i","col_j","val_v");
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      printf("%6d, %6d, %6d, %12.4e\n",i,row_i[i],col_j[i],val_v[i]);
   }
   //if ( false ) {
   //wrap raw input pointers with thrust::device_ptr
   thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_I(row_i);
   printf("initialized row_i into thrust\n");
   thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_J(col_j);
   printf("initialized col_j into thrust\n");
   thrust::device_ptr<float> wrapped_device_V(val_v);
   printf("initialized val_v into thrust\n");

   //use array1d_view to wrap individual arrays
   typedef typename cusp::array1d_view< thrust::device_ptr<int> > DeviceIndexArrayView;
   printf("defined CUSP integer array view for row_i and col_j\n");
   typedef typename cusp::array1d_view< thrust::device_ptr<float> > DeviceValueArrayView;
   printf("defined CUSP float array view for val_v\n");

   DeviceIndexArrayView row_indices(wrapped_device_I, wrapped_device_I + nnz);
   printf("loaded row_i into a CUSP integer array view\n");
   DeviceIndexArrayView column_indices(wrapped_device_J, wrapped_device_J + nnz);
   printf("loaded col_j into a CUSP integer array view\n");
   DeviceValueArrayView values(wrapped_device_V, wrapped_device_V + nnz);
   printf("loaded val_v into a CUSP float array view\n");

   //combine array1d_views into coo_matrix_view
   typedef cusp::coo_matrix_view<DeviceIndexArrayView,DeviceIndexArrayView,DeviceValueArrayView> DeviceView;
   printf("defined CUSP coo_matrix view\n");

   //construct coo_matrix_view from array1d_views
   DeviceView A(n,n,nnz,row_indices,column_indices,values);
   printf("Built matrix A from CUSP device views\n");

   cusp::print(A);
   printf("Printed matrix A\n");
 //}
}
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

**Makefile**

```
Test:
   nvcc -Xcompiler="-fPIC" -shared cusp_runner.cu -o cusp_runner.so -I/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.5/include/cusp
   gfortran -c fort_cusp_test.f90
   gfortran fort_cusp_test.o cusp_runner.so -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.5/lib -lcudart -o fort_cusp_test

clean:
   rm *.o *.so fort_cusp_test
```

---

Functional version of **cusp_runner.cu**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cusp/coo_matrix.h>
#include <iostream>
// #include <cusp/krylov/cg.h>
#include <cusp/print.h>

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

void test_coo_mat_print_(int * row_i, int * col_j, float * val_v, int * N, int * NNZ ) {

   int n, nnz;

   n = *N;
   nnz = *NNZ;

   printf("n: %d, nnz: %d\n",n,nnz);

   printf("printing input (row_i, col_j, val_v)\n");
   printf("%6s, %6s, %6s, %12s \n","i","row_i","col_j","val_v");
   for(int i=0;i<nnz;i++) {
      printf("%6d, %6d, %6d, %12.4e\n",i,row_i[i],col_j[i],val_v[i]);
   }

   printf("initializing thrust device vectors\n");
   thrust::device_vector<int> device_I(row_i,row_i+nnz);
   printf("device_I initialized\n");
   thrust::device_vector<int> device_J(col_j,col_j+nnz);
   printf("device_J initialized\n");
   thrust::device_vector<float> device_V(val_v,val_v+nnz);
   printf("device_V initialized\n");

   cusp::coo_matrix<int, float, cusp::device_memory> A(n,n,nnz);
   printf("initialized empty CUSP coo_matrix on device\n");

   A.row_indices = device_I;
   printf("loaded device_I into A.row_indices\n");
   A.column_indices = device_J;
   printf("loaded device_J into A.column_indices\n");
   A.values = device_V;
   printf("loaded device_V into A.values\n");

   cusp::print(A);
   printf("Printed matrix A\n");
 //}
}
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

Comment: I know nothing about Thrust, but it looks strange to me that the lines for defining DeviceIndexArrayView has n, nnz, nnz, while the line for definining DeviceView has n, n, nnz. Are these correct...? Also, I guess attaching "cuda" tag will be useful.

Comment: Not many people subscribe to [tag:fortran90], if you want some attention, use [tag:fortran]. Besides, the interface you commented out is Fortran 2003, definitely not 90.

Comment: the line for defining DeviceView is definitely correct. I am assuming a square matrix with n rows, n columns and nnz non-zero entries. I have a typo on the definition for row_indices, which should be nnz instead of n, but fixing that did not solve the problem. Thx for the heads up Vladimir. I will indeed be using fortran 90, but I think the problem should still be relevant to fortran in general.

Comment: Another potential source of error is that C arrays assume 0-based indices with row-major memory alignment, while Fortran arrays have 1-based indices while column-major memory alignment. For example, in the Fortran routine you have defined rowI etc with 1-based indices, while Thrust might expect 0-based indices. So could you try modifying rowI and colJ in the Fortran routine as rowI =  (/ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2/) and colJ =  (/ 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2/) and see what happens?

Comment: I tried your suggested but that didn't seem to do the trick... I will need to remember that in the future though. Off by one error could crop up elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thrust/CUSP side code for handling pointers is totally incorrect. This:

```
thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_I(row_i);
```

doesn't do what you think it does. What you have effectively done is cast a host address into a device address. That is illegal unless you are working with CUDA managed memory, and I see no evidence of that in this code. What you want to do is allocate memory and copy the Fortran arrays to the GPU before starting. Do something like:

```
thrust::device_ptr<int> wrapped_device_I = thrust::device_malloc<int>(nnz);
thrust::copy(row_i, row_i + nnz, wrapped_device_I);
```

[disclaimer: totally untested, use at own risk]

For each of the COO vectors. I would, however, suggest replacing most of the code in the GPU setup section of `test_coo_mat_print_` with `thrust::vector` instances instead. Apart from being easier to use, you get free memory deallocation when they fall out of scope so that there is far less possibility of engineering memory leaks. So something like:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> device_I(row_i, row_i + nnz);
```

takes care of everything in a single call.

As a final tip, if you are developing multi-language codebases, design them such that the code in each language is fully independent and has its own native test code. If you had done that in this case, you would have discovered that the C++ part was not working independently of whatever Fortran problems you were having. It would have made debugging much simpler.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. After building the thrust device_vector structures I was able to build A perfectly. This is the first time I've tried building a matrix in CUSP from device vectors, so I was quite lost. Most of the examples I've seen loaded them from a matrix market file or directly initialized the values individually. This is much cleaner.